# Why has the MacOs Diagnostic Log shown an asterisk in an application path?

Tags: logs, macos, superduper

SuperDuper! crashed recently, and when looking at the report I found

```
/Applications/Tools/*/SuperDuper!.app/Contents/MacOS/SuperDuper!
```

The surprising part is the `*`, which I've never seen before. Under what circumstances does macOS use this?

---

**Lots of background information**

While chasing down why SuperDuper! consistently hangs when quitting after doing a backup, I noticed a peculiar line in this .hang file:

From /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SuperDuper!_2019-06-27-154852_taryn-Palantir-2904.hang

```
...
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.13.4 (Build 17E199)
Architecture:    x86_64
Report Version:  26

Data Source:     Stackshots

Command:         SuperDuper!
Path:            /Applications/Tools/*/SuperDuper!.app/Contents/MacOS/SuperDuper!
Identifier:      com.blacey.SuperDuper!
Version:         3.2.5 (119)
...
```

Note the application's path.  Putting aside the weirdness of an exclamation point in a path*, the asterisk at Tools/*/Superduper!.app has me completely perplexed.

I first checked other hang files to see if that was simply an artifact of the logger,  but none show a similar behavior:

```
Command: Arduino
Path:    /Volumes/VOLUME/Applications/Tools/Arduino1.8.9.app/Contents/MacOS/Arduino

Command: com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
Path:    /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent

Process: Console [1600]
Path:    /Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/MacOS/Console
```

The asterisk doesn't appear in the finder, nor in shell listings:

```
Palantir_ethernet:Tools taryn$ pwd
/Applications/Tools
Palantir_ethernet:Tools taryn$ ls -Al
total 129752
...
drwxr-xr-x   3 taryn  staff        96 Sep 27  2018 Slack.app/
drwxr-xr-x   3 taryn  staff        96 Jul 15  2018 SourceTree.app/
drwxr-xr-x   7 taryn  admin       224 Jun 26 15:16 SuperDuper/
drwxr-xr-x@  3 taryn  staff        96 Oct 16  2015 The Hit List.app/
drwxr-xr-x   3 taryn  admin        96 May 31  2014 TimeTracker.app/
drwxr-xr-x@  3 taryn  admin        96 Oct  6  2015 TinkerTool.app/
...
```

(note the '@' by the permissions tells us that there are extended attributes on those files.)

I'd thought momentarily it was an instance of the -F arg of ls.
From 'man ls':

```
...
     -F      Display a slash (`/') immediately after each pathname that is a
             directory, an asterisk (`*') after each that is executable, an at
             sign (`@') after each symbolic link, an equals sign (`=') after
             each socket, a percent sign (`%') after each whiteout, and a ver-
             tical bar (`|') after each that is a FIFO.
...
```

But that doesn't wash, the asterisk lands in a different spot:

```
Palantir_ethernet:Tools taryn$ ls -AlF SuperDuper/SuperDuper\!.app/Contents/MacOS/
total 3216
-r-sr-xr-x  1 root   staff    34720 Jun 24 22:48 SDAgent*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 taryn  staff   445184 Jun 24 22:48 SDCopy*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 taryn  staff    94736 Jun 24 22:48 SDDiskTool*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 taryn  staff    28176 Jun 24 22:48 SDUtil*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 taryn  staff  1036016 Jun 24 22:48 SuperDuper!*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 taryn  staff  1036016 Jun 24 22:48 SuperDuper!*
```

Nor did drilling through the App's folders offer any insight:

```
Palantir_ethernet:Tools taryn$ ls -AlF SuperDuper/SuperDuper\!.app/Contents
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  24 taryn  staff   768 Jun 24 22:48 Frameworks/
drwxr-xr-x   5 taryn  staff   160 Jun 24 22:48 Helpers/
-rw-r--r--   1 taryn  staff  5033 Jun 24 22:47 Info.plist
drwxr-xr-x   7 taryn  staff   224 Jun 24 22:48 MacOS/
-rw-r--r--   1 taryn  staff     8 Jun 24 22:47 PkgInfo
drwxr-xr-x  53 taryn  staff  1696 Jun 24 22:48 Resources/
drwxr-xr-x   3 taryn  staff    96 Jun 24 22:48 _CodeSignature/
-rw-r--r--   1 taryn  staff   504 Jun 24 22:48 version.plist
Palantir_ethernet:Tools taryn$ ls -AlF SuperDuper/SuperDuper\!.app
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  10 taryn  staff  320 Jun 24 22:48 Contents/
Palantir_ethernet:Tools taryn$ ls -AlF SuperDuper/SuperDuper
ls: SuperDuper/SuperDuper: No such file or directory
Palantir_ethernet:Tools taryn$ ls -AlF SuperDuper
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 taryn  admin  6148 Jun 23 21:44 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x  4 taryn  admin   128 Dec 20  2006 Application Support/
drwxr-xr-x@ 4 taryn  admin   128 Sep 15  2015 ReadMe.rtfd/
drwxr-xr-x  3 taryn  staff    96 Jun 26 15:16 SuperDuper!.app/
-rw-------@ 1 taryn  admin  5670 Dec 20  2006 com.blacey.SuperDuper!.plist
```

Searching the net for stuff like 'MacOS application path asterisk' was fruitless, a few hits reminding us that '*' is a legal char in HFS paths, but you'll need to quote or escape it from the shell. Many hits on wildcard expansion.

So, while I'm still trying to understand the crash, this question is whether such a path element has any purpose.

In normal use, a UNIX OS would take that to mean "expand/enumerate all directories under 'Tools/' which contain a subpath like 'SuperDuper!.app/Contents/MacOS/SuperDuper!' ".  Such a usage makes no sense in the context of a log entry that is reporting an explicit known location.

But HFS is a bit weird, in that it is exceptionally permissive of special chars in paths, provided the char is escaped or the path quoted when used from the shell or system calls.

I'm down a classic rabbit hole, I set out to understand a crash, and hours later, I'm still trying to understand how this stupid path got mis-parsed by the logger.

*I've always thought it was bad form to use special chars in paths and files, even though MacOS and HFS/APFS allow it.

Comment: I just noticed that a couple of the folders in Tools/SuperDuper date from 2006, which tells me two things: I've been a fan and licensee of the tool for at least 13 years. And that I should peek in Application Support/ and the .plist file to see if they are backlevel, and perhaps being referenced instead of current versions.

Comment: Is this about diagnosing the hang? If there aren’t good answers in a couple days, the title might need to be refined and some of the potential clues put in an answer. Lots of great data, though and a mystery makes for a good plot twist, perhaps.

Comment: @bmike I'm not sure what you mean by 'this'. This question is specifically pursuing the weird path string being generated by the log. OTOH, my subsequent comment was about diagnosing the hang, and I may yet create a question specific to that. That 'why hung' question probably belongs in a Mac programming stack community, not here.

Comment: I guess I was confused since there was no question in the body and the narrative seemed more like a blog post and avoiding asking the v nor for support. Don’t Ming my comments if you don’t feel they will help.

Comment: With all the detailed analysis, the ping to Shirt Pocket and the additional information in the comments it's hard to tell what (if any) your question actually is. Especially if the issue is related to having a long-running installation of SuperDuper! it might be difficult to diagnose by others without access to your system.

Comment: @nohillside A fair point. I've re-edited to make clear that the question is about the path, not about the crash.

Comment: No takers on what a wildcard in the middle of a fully defined path means, but I did discover that at some point over the last 13 years, Blacey.com changed SuperDuper's install from drag-n-drop to run-first-from-dmg. I'd never noticed this, since their updater always 'just worked' as I copied my environment from mac to mac, letting SuperDuper update itself as needed. Re-installing from the current release fixed the crash.